# Getting a thrown exception error when trying to update db

Tags: php, mysql, exception, prepared-statement

I created a page where I can edit user information. I am only performing a prepared statement off of one db table called 'users' and in the users db table I have a column called group where I can assign users different permission levels. I am outputting the current data for the user I selected onto this page, so if a user has a group level of 1, in the option field it will show 1. I then have 4 other options which I list the other values at 2, 3, 4, and 5. Whenever I try to submit the form I am getting an exception error from my user class "There was a problem updating!". There update function is below where the exception error is...

```
public function update($fields = array(), $id = null) {

    if(!$id && $this->isLoggedIn()) {
        $id = $this->data()->id;
    }

    if(!$this->_db->update('users', $id, $fields)) {
        throw new Exception('There was a problem updating!');
    }
}
```

I believe my prepared statement and form is sound other than possibly the group option area. I want the current group number to be displayed in the option box and if I do not need to update it, I want to be able to click submit and not have any issues and I want to be able to update the group integer.

This is the part I am not sure if it is correct or enabling me to do this..

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="group">Group</label>
    <select name="group" required>
        <option value=''><?php echo htmlentities($group); ?></option>
        <option value="1">Bench</option>
        <option value="2">Spectator</option>
        <option value="3">Team Member</option>
        <option value="4">Commissioner</option>
        <option value="5">Creator</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is my prepared statement and form...

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
/* check connection */
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT firstname, lastname, email, username, `group` FROM users WHERE id = ?");
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
  // Check Errors for prepare
  die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
}
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_GET['id']);
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
      // Check errors for binding parameters
      die('bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
$stmt->execute();
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
      die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
    //Check errors for execute
//if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$con->error, E_USER_WARNING);}
$stmt->bind_result($firstname, $lastname, $email, $username, $group);
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->fetch()) { ?>
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="firstname" class="inputbar" value="<?php echo htmlentities($firstname); ?>" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="lastname" class="inputbar" value="<?php echo htmlentities($lastname); ?>" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="inputbaremail" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlentities($email); ?>" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                            <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="username" value="<?php echo htmlentities($username); ?>" required>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="group">Group</label>
                            <select name="group" required>
                                <option value=''><?php echo htmlentities($group); ?></option>
                                <option value="1">Bench</option>
                                <option value="2">Spectator</option>
                                <option value="3">Team Member</option>
                                <option value="4">Commissioner</option>
                                <option value="5">Creator</option>
                            <!--<input type="text" class="inputbar" name="group" value="<?php //echo htmlentities($group); ?>" required>-->
                            </select>
                        </div>  

                            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
                            <label for="signinButton">
                                <input type="submit" id="signinButton" value="Update">
                            </label>
                    </form>
<?php } else { ?>

     User <?php echo htmlentities($_GET['id']); ?> not found.
<? 
} ?>
```

Does anyone see anything that would be preventing this to go through?

UPDATE:

```
public function update($fields = array(), $id = null) {

    if(!$id && $this->isLoggedIn()) {
        $id = $this->data()->id;
    }
    echo $this->_db->update('users', $id, $fields);
}
    //if(!$this->_db->update('users', $id, $fields)) {
        //throw new Exception('There was a problem updating!');
    //}

     //if(!$this->_db->update('users', $id, $fields)) { 
    // throw new Exception('There was a problem updating!')->getMessage(); 
     //}
//}
```

NEW CODE WITH INSERT PREPARED STATEMENT ADDED. STILL NOT SENDING

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $firstname = Input::get('firstname');
    $lastname = Input::get('lastname');
    $email = Input::get('email');
    $username = Input::get('username');
    $group = 1;




$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
        /* check connection */
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }
        $stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, username, `group`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?");
        if ( false===$stmt2 ) {
        // Check Errors for prepare
            die('User Request prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
        }
        $stmt2->bind_param('sssssi', $firstname, $lastname, $email, $username, $group);
        if ( false===$stmt2 ) {
        // Check errors for binding parameters
            die('User Request bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
        }
        $stmt2->execute();
        if ( false===$stmt2 ) {
            die('User Request execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
        }
    }



//Prepared statement that gets user info    
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
/* check connection */
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT firstname, lastname, email, username, `group` FROM users WHERE id = ?");
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
  // Check Errors for prepare
  die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
}
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_GET['id']);
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
      // Check errors for binding parameters
      die('bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
$stmt->execute();
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
      die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
    //Check errors for execute
//if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$con->error, E_USER_WARNING);}
$stmt->bind_result($firstname, $lastname, $email, $username, $group);
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->fetch()) { ?>
```

Trying to use try/catch...

```
public function update($fields = array(), $id = null) {

    if(!$id && $this->isLoggedIn()) {
        $id = $this->data()->id;
    }
    //echo $this->_db->update('users', $id, $fields);

    //if(!$this->_db->update('users', $id, $fields)) {
        //throw new Exception('There was a problem updating!');
    //}
    try {
        if(!$this->_db->update('users', $id, $fields)) {
            throw new Exception('There was a problem updating!');
        }
    }
       catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "An error occurred";
    throw $e;
        }
        finally {
                    //This overrides the exception as if it were never thrown
            return "\nException erased";
            }
            try {
            echo asdf();
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            echo "\nResult: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

I get this error..

```
An error occurred
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home4/db/public_html/example.com/classes/User.php:46) in /home4/db/public_html/example.com/classes/Redirect.php on line 14
```

Line 45 of my user class is this..

```
        echo "An error occurred";
```

Comment: try executing this line outside the if statement `$this->_db->update('users', $id, $fields)` and see what error you get

Comment: I get this syntax error with that code... `unexpected '->' (`

Comment: the code should be inside your function.  `public function update($fields = array(), $id = null) {

    if(!$id && $this->isLoggedIn()) {
        $id = $this->data()->id;
    }

    echo $this->_db->update('users', $id, $fields);

}`

Comment: It goes through, but nothing changes in my db. It doesn't give me an error. I will add in the code to my quest like I have it in my user class .

Comment: Where's the `update` SQL/DB interaction?

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think about that. I don't have an update/insert query. So that is why that update error was coming up right? How would it know I was trying to update though?

Comment: I created an insert prepared statement that if the submit button was set it would insert my users table, but nothing is still happening. I updated my question to show what I have.

Comment: Consider removing the custom Exception message ('There was a problem updating!') with actual error message, possibly wth [try/catch](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) to better diagnose. Also, check your users table for `NOT NULL` field constraint. Even more, your bind_param has six types 'sssssi' when you are importing five values.

Comment: @Parfait I took out one of the s's in the bind_param and I tried doing the try/catch like you stated, it is throwing the error in my code, I updated my question to show how I was trying to do the try/catch...not sure if it is right. None-the-less, nothing was inserted into my db.

Comment: Looking deeper, I am seeing several issues here. You call the `update()` within `update()` function. You have a missing action in `form` so unaware of how PHP will process submission. Error seems to address something at the top of your script: `header();`, `session_start();`, or `ob_start();` which must always precede any HTML code or echo/print output. Finally can you clean up the redundancy in your posted code, confusing the flow? And consider moving this thread over to [SO Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: I added edituser.php to the form action to redirect back to that page. I'm not sure what you mean  by "You call the update() within update() function.". I have my init.php file at the top of my screen on the 3 line, right after the php error checking code. What is so redundant of my code? Please let me know so I can learn.